# problema com audio phonegap/cordova

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova, plugin, áudio

Estou usando o plugin cordova-plugin-media para executar áudio no meu app e esta funcionando perfeitamente, porém ao iniciar o áudio no meu app, o áudio que esta rolando em outra aplicação para de ser executado. Gostaria de uma solução para esse problema, preciso que o áudio continue a ser executado na aplicação que esta em background.
Existe algum plugin que faça isso ou alguma configuração que estou deixando passar?

Answer (score 1):

A quem possa interessar:

Consegui solucionar o meu problema trocando o plugin utilizado, encontrei esse plugin **cordova-plugin-nativeaudio** que atendeu completamente as minhas necessidades.